# How to add SSL/TLS to domain in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an issue I've been working on in aws. I have a website made for a friend and can't seem to get the connection secure. What I used is the certificate manager in aws and have received a certificate for my domain. Here's one of the links I used as an example. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-certificate-manager-deploy-ssltls-based-apps-on-aws/ I have followed examples online but they seem to be for load balancer's. What I'm a missing?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a useful tutorial and I share it with you how to setup your domain with s3 Bucket and CloudFront from AWS https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uwgB_sIhIko&t=321s